# Spring Hibernate Integration

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am new to Spring Hibernate. I was trying Spring Hibernate integration tutorial from `http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html`
and i was able to run the example.This example deals with one table.

Now i am trying with one more table. I have few question

As per my understanding we need to add following things

1. DAOinterface
2. DAOimpl
3. table POJO

so

- Is this the only way to add more tables ?
- Do  we need  to add one more controller for the new table if it belongs to new form.
- How we will add this new table entry to dispatcher-servlet.xml

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you posted is highly simplistic. You can arrange things any way you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend learning Spring Hiberate integration using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/start) as a kick starter application - which can be customized to use any JPA2 implementation (Hibernate, Eclipse Link etc). One of the things you will notice though is that Spring ROO web application does not have a dedicated DAO layer at all, instead preferring to use the [Active Record Pattern](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/ROO-301). Using Spring Roo you will be very quickly able to come up with an end to end working web application, then you can go through the underlying generated codebase, configuration to better understand how the Spring, Hibernate integration works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same DAO to persist any no. of tables like,let another table is manager,in same DAO u can use like this

public void saveUser(Manager mgr) {
hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(mgr);
}
public List listManagers() {
return hibernateTemplate.find("from Manager");
}

Answer (score 0):

@Aj, this might be too late for you. But for those who are reading this, you can follow this guide [Spring - Hibernate: One-To-Many Association](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/03/spring-hibernate-one-to-many.html) which shows you step by step in configuring a Spring MVC 3 and Hibernate Annotations and using one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a new table:**
To add new table you need create a new Hibernate POJO and add these lines in dispatcher-servlet.xml;

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>com.vaannila.domain.User</value>
<value>com.vaannila.domain.AnotherTableClassBean</value>
<value>...</value>
<value>....</value>
</list>
```

OR Read on "Packagescan" to scan all tables in a package that map to table.

**Controller:**

When you want to handle a new request from browser then a controller is used.
If your controller extends AbstractController then you need to create new class for new request OR if you use MultiActionController then you need to add new method to cater to new request.

**DAOinterface & Impl Classes:**

Creating a new DAO and interface is only to separate your queries for two different tables. You can choose to fire all queries from same DAO or separate them based on functionality(all dashboard queries, etc) or Table queries(table 1, table 2,etc).